# How to kill and remove docker containers using puppet

Tags: docker, docker-compose, puppet

I would like to add a scheduled job (fortnightly) to a machine using puppet to remove all containers on machine.

Currently I need to do `sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q)` manually after sshing to that machine, which I want to automate.

Preferably using module: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/docker.
Can't see any option to kill and remove containers (also new to puppet). Even using `docker-compose` using puppet is fine.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The docs you linked say:

> To remove a running container, add the following code to the manifest file. This also removes the systemd service file associated with the container.
>
> ```
> docker::run { 'helloworld':
>  ensure => absent,
> }
> ```

Regarding the docker command `sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q)` to remove containers via ssh, you have a better one:

```
$ docker container prune --help

Usage:  docker container prune [OPTIONS]

Remove all stopped containers

Options:
      --filter filter   Provide filter values (e.g. 'until=<timestamp>')
  -f, --force           Do not prompt for confirmation
```

So the equivalent would be:

```
docker container prune --force
```

And you can automate this ssh command via puppet, no need to manually ssh into the machine. Check their docs to [run shell commands](https://puppet.com/docs/discovery/1.x/pd_task.html#reference-7024) without installing an agent, or use [Bolt command](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/running_bolt_commands.html) if you already have an agent installed on the remote host.